# Come up on hover

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking for a similar function https://www.squareweave.com.au/work. When hove the tablet it comes up. I want exactly same feature but a little bit different elements. My idea is to put up 3 mobile devised on the header of my site half hidden but when hover they should come up like the above url.

I believe it can be accomplish using the css but I have no idea how to control speed.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element with the browser DOM tools? What code have you tried? What do and don't you understand? Do you have any examples?

Comment: Please add some examples of code that you have tried on codepen.io or a similar site, it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's easy, here your have the code of the page you have spoken about:

```
margin-bottom: -30px;
transition: all .15s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all .15s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: all .15s ease-out;
```

And on hover:

```
margin-bottom: 0;
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: While this is correct, I don't think it's good to just post an answer if the original poster makes no effort and doesn't post any attempted `CSS`

Comment: Yes you are right but maybe that user has not any knowledge about CSS and it's too difficult to him search something about...

Comment: If he has no knowledge of CSS he probably should be on sites where he can read documentation and tutorials about it.